# How to set ConstraintLayout End of Top Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How to set botton group layout_constraintEnd_toTopOf Bottom Sheet
And when swipe up or swipe down the button group follow that

I've tried several methods but I still can't get like red arrow below.

[image]

this below is main xml
I used CoordinatorLayout between fragment and linearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="40.73581"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-73.99155"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="11"/>

    </FrameLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_options_inside"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/toggleButtonGroup2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:singleSelection="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            >


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
                style="@style/ToggleButtonWithIconOnly"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_near_me_24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="168dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="153dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCenter"
                style="@style/ToggleButtonWithIconOnly"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="173dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="251dp" />

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>




</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

below is my include bottom sheet xml layout
I try to add ConstraintLayout layout in LinearLayout but I can't use bottom sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="?actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottomsheet"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_remove_24"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                />
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank for your all answer

Answer (score 0):

Try anchoring your toggle group to your bottom sheet

```
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="end"
```

Comment: Not work  it's stacked on CoordinatorLayout